# Help with German student visa application situation

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I am from India and I visited Germany last year. In the itinerary I submitted with my Schengen visa application I mentioned that I wanted to travel to Poland, Czech, Austria and Hungary. However during my actual trip, I changed my itinerary a bit and I also spent a considerable amount of time in Germany. I will be going there again this year as a student.

I am now applying for a German student visa. In the student visa application it asks if I have visited Germany earlier. Would it be right to reveal that I have visited earlier? Would this be taken negatively, since I had not mentioned it in my itinerary? Or can I just hide the fact and mention that I have not visited Germany earlier? During my stay in Germany, I stayed in hostels, and was asked to submit a copy of my passport. Is there any way for the Germany embassy to find out my earlier trip to Germany?

I am trying to figure out what would be the best thing to write in my application. Thank you for the help!

Comment: By ‘hide the fact’ you mean lie in your application? That’s a sure way not to get a visa. The best thing to write in any visa application is the unvarnished truth, clear and simple.

Answer (score 3):

It is (almost) always a bad idea to lie on a visa application, and we advise **strongly** against it. Legal and moral reasons aside, one "little" lie might force you to lie again in the next document to keep everything consistent, and so on, until the lies break down.

Your change in itinerary was probably OK *if* you made it in good faith after the visa application and not deceptively before the application. That makes lying about it even more foolish. So the best option would be to tell the truth -- you had passed through Germany on your way from Poland to Hungary (or whatever the Schengen countries before and after Germany on your trip had been).

Re the registration, the authorities can look into them, but they are not routinely examined. They may or may not be deleted by now.